# extremely huge number in assembly code but invalid in C++

Tags: c++, boost, casting, x86, disassembly

In a disassembled code(probably compiled by visual studio), I found such a code:

```
label:
dt 1.189713341495303E+4932
```

What does it mean? why should someone use such number?

`boost::lexical_cast<double>("1.189713341495303E+4932")` fails conversion of this number. If it is out of range, why is it allowed in assembly?

Comment: Did you try a `long double `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value is close to `LDBL_MAX` in `float.h` on most systems - it's the maximum value of a `long double`:

```
$ grep LDBL_MAX float.h
#define LDBL_MAX    __LDBL_MAX__

$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep __LDBL_MAX__
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L
```